# Classification for linear systems

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

can someone explain to me the classifications for linear equations? I don't understand what the terms mean. Consistent, inconsistent, and dependent and how a system of equations can be both.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of a set of `M` linear equations as relationships between `N` variables. The equations in the set determine if the set is

- consistent
- in-consistent or
- dependent

Easiest to understand is category in-consistent. Example:

```
x +  y = 10
x +  y = 12
```

As you can see the right hand side is in-consistent. So you get gist of what inconsistent means.
Now let's see example of dependent:

```
 x +  y = 10
2x + 2y = 20
```

We have same equation written in different form.

Finally if the set is neither in-consistent, nor dependent, then it is usually consistent.